# Select all sound in a tab in order to adjust them

Tags: javascript

I am looking for create a firefox addon in which we can adjust the sound with a slidebar and a mute button.

After many hours and many tests of research i can't find how to "select" the sound with a js script but ihave the menu, the popup etc but i block on the js

The goal of the extension is to select all the sound of a tab (iframe, direct flux, audio, video, etc.) in order to adjust the sound in direct class or youtube etc.

I know is very difficult, maybe impossible to have a 100% working rate but i want to approach the 100%

I hope you can help me

```js
var audio = document.getElementsByTagName("video", "audio", "iframe");
function enableMute() {
    audio.muted = true;
}
```

```css
html, body {
    width: 200px;
    height: 160px;
    font-family: 'Righteous', cursive;
    background-color: #2F3136;
    overflow: hidden;
    color: #DCDDDE;
  }
  
  #popsoundtext {
    padding-top: 10px;
    margin: auto;
    text-align: center;
  }
  .popsound {
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    margin: auto;
    width: 130px;
      
  }
    #volume1 {
        cursor: pointer;
        background: #7289da;
        height: 10px;
        width: 130px;
        border-radius: 50px;
        -webkit-appearance: none;
  }



  .onetap {
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    margin: auto;
    width: 90px;
      
  }
  #onetaptext {
    padding-top: 10px;
    margin: auto;
    text-align: center;
  }

  #onebutton {
    border: none;
    border-radius: 90px;
    height: 20px;
    width: 40px;
    background-color: #7289da;
    color: #DCDDDE;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: 'Righteous', cursive;
  }
  #secondbutton {
    border: none;
    border-radius: 90px;
    height: 20px;
    background-color: #7289da;
    color: #DCDDDE;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: 'Righteous', cursive;
    float: right;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="soundpop.css"/>
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com"> 
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Righteous&display=swap" rel="stylesheet"> 

  </head>

  <body>
    <p id="popsoundtext"> Swipe to adjust : </p>



    <div class="popsound">
        <input id="volume1" type="range" onchange="setVolume()"  min="0" max="10" value="10">
    </div>

    <p id="onetaptext"> Fast command : </p>


    <div class="onetap">
        <button id="onebutton" onclick="low()">Low</button>



      <button id="secondbutton" onclick="enableMute()">Mute</button>
    </div>
    
    
    
    <script src="soundpop.js"></script>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Please share some code, what you are trying, what is the expected input and what is the expected output example. Thanks

Comment: I don't have it with me (i'm in classe) i send it in 8hours. My JS is empty because i don't find something work but i can put my last attempt. I put here a picture to show a preview of the extension [link](https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/621740287345295389/825743413818949642/unknown.png?width=1248&height=683)

Comment: I put now the code